# Email Logo changed after updates Magento 1.9

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.9, skin, graphical-logo

After every update I do my Email logos are reset to a default Magento logo on order emails.

When I check my Admin configuration it is still the correct logo. 
Also if I if I check the media/email/logo/default it is the correct logo.

I use my own skin and the correct logos are still there /skin/frontend/default/MYOWNSKIN/images/logo_email.gif

but they have changed in 
/skin/frontend/default/default/images/logo_email.gif

It always ends up with me changing the files in /skin/frontend/default/default/images/logo_email.gif and a lot of fiddling around with gmail, cache and suddenly it works.

What am I doing wrong? It would be nice not having to do this after next update.

Regards Ronnie